# Get DateTime from FileName

Tags: c#, file, datetime, tryparse

I have a file named `test-2000_01_02-10_12_14.xml`.

How do I only get the date from the file?

I was able to get the date if the file has this name: `2000_01_02-10_12_14`

with this (`b` is a `StorageFile`):

```
DateTime dateVal;
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(b.DisplayName, 
                       "yyyy_MM_dd-H_mm_ss", 
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                        out dateVal);
```

I then tried to change `yyyy_MM_dd-H_mm_ss` to something like this `*-yyyy_MM-dd-H-mm_ss` but it does not seem to be the solution

Comment: What is `b.DisplayName`? Can you `string.Split` on `-`?

Comment: "*but it does not seem to be the solution*" is not a technical (or professional) description of a problem, please paste your error message or describe whats happening (for fun level 100), anyway all that aside, [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8) and or use regex

Comment: @mjwills b.DisplayName is "test-2000_01_02-10_12_14"

Comment: Is it always `test...` or can it start with other characters?

Comment: @TheGeneral there is no error message. parsed receives the value "false". I assume ' * ' in ' *-yyyy_MM_dd-H_mm_ss ' does not substitute "test" in this example

Comment: @DavidG In this case it's always test. (But I also would like to know it for the case when it could be any other name)

Comment: I tried this code and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to *extract* (match) the datetime part from a file name:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ... 

  // Aggravated task: dots and minuses within file's name
  string source = @"bla-bla-bla-test.me-2000_01_02-10_12_14.xml";

  string datetime = Regex.Match(
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source),
   "[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}$").Value;
```

Then we can parse it

```
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        datetime,
       "yyyy_MM_dd-H_m_s",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
        out DateTime result) {
    // result is the parsed date
  }
  else {
    // File doesn't contain valid date and time
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a boatload of ways to do this, it really rather depends on how regular the naming of your files is - is there always some junk text followed by a hyped, then the year?

Post up another 10 different examples if you want more tailored advice. Here's a way for the one you've posted:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(b.DisplayName.Substring(b.DisplayName.IndexOf('-')+1)), 
  "yyyy_MM_dd-H_mm_ss", 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
  out dateVal
);
```

This uses Substring with only one argument (no length) to remove everything after the first hyphen up to the end of the string, and GetFileNameWithoutExtension to remove the .xml - this effectively turns `anythinghere-2000_01_01-00_00_00.xml` into `2000_01_01-00_00_00` ready for parsing

I could also have gone for a `.Remove("last index of period")` type thing but it does get a bit messy because you have to subtract the start Index of the hyphen etc

MJWill's comment about splitting on hyphen is also a good one - you could split then take the `[1]` and `[2]` indexes and join then back together for parsing..

Lastly don't forget that the file itself might have a created date that is already a good candidate for the date of creation rather than the filename (which might be mangled by humans) so long as it hasn't been transmitted somewhere and re-saved. Take a look at the `FileInfo.CreationTime` property for that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `regular expression` assuming that your file name will be always following the same format you can do something like this:

```
var pattern = @"\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}";

var fileName = "test-2000_01_02-10_12_14.xml";

var match = new Regex(pattern);

var result = match.Match(fileName);

if (result.Success)
{
   DateTime.TryParseExact(result.Value,
                    "yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss",
                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                  out DateTime dateVal);
}
```